# get_object_or_404 not working properly in django

Tags: python, django

when I attempt to get an object with specific slug it gave me 404 page error, however I've hard coded the slug name and that worked and I've printed the slug field separately and it was the one that I've already tested before.
this the view part:

```
def show_category(request, hierarchy=None):
    category_slug = hierarchy.split('/')
    category_queryset = list(Category.objects.all())
    all_slugs = [x.slug for x in category_queryset]
    print(all_slugs)
    print(get_object_or_404(Product, title='benz'))
    parent = None
    for slug in category_slug:
        if slug in all_slugs:
            parent = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=slug, parent=parent)
        else:
            # these 3 lines bellow:

            print(slug)
            print(get_object_or_404(Product, slug='benz'))
            instance = get_object_or_404(Product, slug=slug)

            breadcrumbs_link = instance.get_cat_list()
            breadcrumbs_name = instance.get_cat_names()
            category_name = [' '.join(i.split('/')[-1].split('-'))
                             for i in breadcrumbs_name]
            breadcrumbs = zip(breadcrumbs_link, category_name)
            return render(request, "products/product_detail.html", {'instance': instance, 'breadcrumbs': breadcrumbs})


    return render(request, "products/products_list.html", {'product_set': parent.product_set.all(), 'sub_categories': parent.children.all()})
```

and these are Product and Category models:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(allow_unicode=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(
        'self', blank=True, null=True, related_name='children', on_delete=models.CASCADE)


    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('slug', 'parent',)
        verbose_name_plural = "categories"

    @property
    def get_products(self):
        return Product.objects.filter(category__name=self.name)

class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(verbose_name='desription')
    slug = models.SlugField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='product_pics', default='default.jpg')
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        'Category', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('product-detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

    def get_cat_list(self):
        k = self.category
        breadcrumb = ["dummy"]
        while k is not None:
            breadcrumb.append(k.slug)
            k = k.parent
        for i in range(len(breadcrumb)-1):
            breadcrumb[i] = '/'.join(breadcrumb[-1:i-1:-1])
        return breadcrumb[-1:0:-1]

    def get_cat_names(self):
        k = self.category
        breadcrumb = ["dummy"]
        while k is not None:
            breadcrumb.append(k.name)
            k = k.parent
        for i in range(len(breadcrumb)-1):
            breadcrumb[i] = '/'.join(breadcrumb[-1:i-1:-1])
        return breadcrumb[-1:0:-1]
```

Comment: Looks like it might contain a space, or another envisible character. What if you `print(repr(slug))`? Then you get the string literal, which thus makes hidden characters visible.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I checked but no difference and I checked if they are equal and got True

Comment: My assumption: you have trailing `/`, which results in empty string item after `split`, which is not visually detectable with current implementation because `print(slug)` gives just a blank line, thus you see only your correct slug in console output - after prior iteration.